# Array.prototype.filter() returns empty list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to filter a list of jQuery elements collected using the .siblings() method.
I have the html code:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input class="form-control username" type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username"/>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="Password">Password</label>
        <input class="form-control password" type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password"/>
    </div>

    <div style="text-align:center;">
         <button id="login">Login</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the button is pressed, I collect the sibling divs using:

```
var elem = jQuery(this).parent('div').siblings('div:has(input)');
```

This returns an array of length 2 (containing the divs of both the username and password).

When I then check to see if the first item in this array has a child input tag with class 'username' the following code returns true.

```
jQuery(elem[0]).children('input').hasClass('username');
```

However, when I filter the array on this condition, an array of length 0 is returned. Why does this happen? Surely the array should contain 1 element since the condition evaluates to true on the first element?

```
var filteredElem = elem.filter(div => jQuery(div).children('input').hasClass('username'));
```

```js
$('#login').click(function() {

  var elem = jQuery(this).parent('div').siblings('div:has(input)');

  var filteredElem = elem.filter(div => jQuery(div).children('input').hasClass('username'));

  console.log(filteredElem.length)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input class="form-control username" type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username" />
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="Password">Password</label>
    <input class="form-control password" type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" />
  </div>

  <div style="text-align:center;">
    <button id="login">Login</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried logging `jQuery(div).children('input')`? Have you tried `$(div).find('input.username').length > 0`?

Comment: Just use `elem.find('input.username');`

Comment: `elem` is not an array, it's an array-like jQuery object. Hence this question is not about [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) but jQuerys [`$.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly note that you're calling the jQuery [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter) method, not the native array [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method as your title implies. This is because `elem` holds a jQuery object, not an array.

The issue itself is because the first argument passed to the jQuery `filter()` handler function is the index of the current element, not a reference to the element itself. As such you need to change the logic to:

```
var filteredElem = elem.filter((i, div) => ...
```

```js
$('#login').click(function() {
  var elem = jQuery(this).parent('div').siblings('div:has(input)');

  var filteredElem = elem.filter((i, div) => jQuery(div).children('input').hasClass('username'));

  console.log(filteredElem.length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input class="form-control username" type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username" />
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="Password">Password</label>
    <input class="form-control password" type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" />
  </div>

  <div style="text-align:center;">
    <button id="login">Login</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

That being said, you can simplify this example to just use `find()` instead of explicitly looping through all the sibling divs:

```js
$('#login').click(function() {
  var $username = $(this).parent('div').siblings('div:has(input)').find('.username');      
  console.log($username.length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input class="form-control username" type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username" />
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="Password">Password</label>
    <input class="form-control password" type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" />
  </div>

  <div style="text-align:center;">
    <button id="login">Login</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Even simpler still would be to use the `submit` event of your login `form` and then `find()` the `.username` within that:

```
$('#yourLoginForm').on('submit', function() {
  var $username = $(this).find('.username');
});
```

Comment: Great answer, this is more a question for the OP, but why a selector on the class and not the id?

Comment: It maybe worth pointing out that this difference in the ordering of the arguments is for _JQuery's_ `filter` callback; the OP thinks that the issue is the way that _Array.prototype.filter_ is working.

Comment: @George very good point! I was so wrapped up in simplifying the DOM traversal I didn't even spot the inputs themselves had ids! *facepalm*